# Getting the id of a table row when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox inside a table row

```
<tr id="1">
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td>lorem</td>
<td>ipsum</td>
<td>css</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the id when the checkbox is checked

I have tried this

```
var closestTr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');

alert(closestTr);
```

I also tried this http://jsfiddle.net/AbfJk/3/

Why doesn't it get the id?

Comment: as far as i can see your code isn't tied to the button click. how are you expecting it to fire?

Comment: Your JSFiddle has a syntax error in the JS and isn't including the jQuery extension.

Comment: That is a mistake,it should be there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
    var closestTr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(closestTr);
});
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AbfJk/7/

anyway, your fiddle is missing jquery and has also a ")" missing (you put the "end comment" in the wrong line)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      alert($(this).parent('tr').attr('id'));

   });

    alert(closestTr);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in your jsfiddle you have not added jquery support. and there were some modifications.
I have done those and i have updated the jsfiddle. Please check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/AbfJk/10/

I have given trigger to a button click. Hope this helps you

```
(function ($) {
        $('#thechecked').click(function () {
            var closestTr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').attr('id');
            alert(closestTr);
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and works.

Plcease run $(':checkbox:checked') in your console. Does it return 
[​] ?

Possible reasons:

- You forgot to include jquery into the page.
- You have multiple checked boxes and got the wrong one returned.
- You have an error in JS somewhere that halts execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

**JQuery**:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        alert(id);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbfJk/11/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
      alert(id);
   }
});
```