# How to post immediately on checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of ToDoItems displayed on a page:

```
@model ToDo4.ViewModels.IndexViewModel  
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)  
{  
    <tr>  
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content) </td>  
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status) </td>  
    </tr>  
}
```

IndexViewModel contains:
`List<ToDoItem>  Items`

I would like to change what is displayed (filter on ToDoItem.Status) immediately when a checkbox is checked or unchecked.
1)  How do I handle the checked/unchecked event and get back to the Controller?
2)  I suspect I should put the list in a partial view; whatever handles the checked/unchecked event would the refresh just the partial view.
Any insights are appreciated...

Comment: I'm wondering if you try to do a little ajax and detect in the action that is an `AjaxRequest` and then return the answer as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a jquery ajax call back to the controller to change the record in the database.  something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: {
        id: 'clicked id'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        var tr = //clicked row
        tr.remove();
    }
});
```

[Getting the id of a table row when a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853364/getting-the-id-of-a-table-row-when-a-checkbox-is-checked)
this has code on how to get the id of the clicked row and you should be able to use that same row with the tr.remove.  tr.remove will remove the table row out of the table.  You mentioned needing to change the list but hopefully remove will accomplish what you are needing.

Comment: Interesting, but I'd like to, on checkbox check/uncheck, post back to the controller.  That way, the controller would have the state of the checkbox in the model, and could gen a new list based on the state of the checkboxes.  The list (in the foreach loop) is in a partial view, so only that part of the page would be updated.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071301/how-to-open-window-in-the-same-view-in-mvc-4/20080267#20080267 for how to use an ajax call to get a new partial view

Comment: @MB: Thanks, I'm getting closer to figuring this out, but I'm getting a number of syntax errors on the url: member.

Comment: use url.action like in my example, just replace the action and controller with your names.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, very helpful.  Got it working, although getting the 'checked' value of the checkbox was a little arcane:  `data: {
                        isChecked: ($(this).is(":checked")),

Comment: glad you got it working and thanks for the heads up on checked