# MVC Get value of a column in a row in a table where checkbox is checked and store in list using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on my first large mvc project and I'm having trouble working out how to get the value of my date column, for each row in my table, where that rows check box is checked/selected and store in list (preferably in my HomeController)

I Found : [Getting the id of a table row when a checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853364/getting-the-id-of-a-table-row-when-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Which lead me to trying a number of changes with the below

```
$("#thechecked").click(function(){
var closestTr = $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr');
alert(closestTr);
});
```

but all i could get was [object Object]

My Table (Can have several thousand rows):

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Test Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checks">
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppModeId)
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

also as a note the above table is within a modal.

Can anyone help by suggest a suitable method to produce this? or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Now using this method to return the dates in an array, im just looking to find out how to post this to a list in my controller using ajax?

```
    $("#resultsgo").click(function () {
        $('.checks:checked').each(function () {
            var createDate = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(1).text();
            var datearray = [];
            datearray.push(createDate); // for testing
        });
    });
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string filtername)        
    {
        HttpCookie cookieUser = Request.Cookies["loginCookie"];
        ViewBag.Username = Server.HtmlEncode(cookieUser.Value);

        var filterresults = from m in db.UserInfoes
                            select m;

        filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.UserCode.ToString().Contains(filtername)).OrderBy(x => x.UserCode);
        CheckDownloaded();
        return View(filterresults);
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to access the list of checked records on the client side using `JavaScript`/`JQuery` or on postback to the server. One thing I would note that if posted back the model data will not be persisted as it is being displayed and therefore there is no `EditorFor` which is used to populate the model posted back. Secondly the way you are displaying (even if these were disabled editors) would not post back to the model correctly, `IEnumerables` generally need to be displayed accessing the property by index e.g. `Model[index].propertyName` not foreach with `item.propertyName`

Comment: Note: the dates correspond to a row of data about a test run on a phone.
I *think* I just need to access the list of checked records on client side, as after I get the returned list of dates I will use these dates to retrieve other details from the model about the test that was carried out on that date (through a linq query in the homecontroller which is displayed in a 3 columns comparison, each column being a test on that phone)

Hope that makes sense i'm pretty new to thinking in a client - server format :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of `CreationDateTime` for each row where the checkbox is checked you can use (I assume `#thechecked` must be the id of a button or some other element on the page)

```
$("#thechecked").click(function() {
  var selectedDates = new Array();
  $('.checks:checked').each(function() {
    var createDate = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(1).text();
    selectedDates.push(createDate); // add to array
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveDates")';
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: {dates: selectedDates },
    success: function(data) {
      // do something with the returned value?
    }
  });
});
```

this may depend on what your `DisplayTemplate` is actually rendering and it may be better to use the following to just add the value in the table cell

```
<td>
  @item.CreationDateTime
</td>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
  foreach(DateTime date in dates)
  {
    // Do something with the date
  }
  return Json(someReturnValue);
}
```

You indicated that you table might *"have several thousand rows"*. If that is the case, you should consider paging to display only say 20-50 rows at a time to improve performance.

Comment: great the above JQuery returns the result which i now push them into an array which ive included above all i'm looking for now is i would like is to pass this array to the controller using ajax and into a list in my controller. could you explain how?

Comment: Edit your question to include the signature for your controller method

Comment: I've updated with the controller (Home/Index)that i need the list in. thanks

Comment: Is `CreationDateTime` type of `DateTime`? i.e. do you want to pass an array of `DateTime` values to the controller? Your linq query suggest something else!

Comment: And are you wanting to post the values and stay on the page, or are you wanting to redirect?

Comment: Yes creationdatetime is a datetime2, I'm just looking to post the values into a list in the controller while im staying on the same page. The linq in the controller is separate and is used for the search process that populates the foreach loop based on a user entered value (filtername).

Comment: You still haven't posted your controller method for the POST action, but I'll update answer based on it being `public ActionResult SaveDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates) {...`